# Google sheet get fasten array for loop

Tags: google-sheets, show-hide

Is it possible to fasten the hide of many rows when range.length > 300 rows ?

I also can't succeed moving the focus to the top of the sheet once the rows are hidden, I can only get the focus on another sheet.

Here is my code (french parameters), I'm not sure I need to show my spreadsheet. Thank you very much.

```
var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
var ToHide = [];
for (var i=1 ; i < LastRow +1 ; i++){
    if ( sheet.getRange(i,1).isChecked() == null){ ToHide.push(i); }
}

for (var j=0 ; j<ToHide.length ; j++){ MyActiveSheet.hideRows(ToHide[j+1],1); }

ToHide.forEach(function (d){ FeuilleActive.hideRows(d); }); // also tried .hideRows(d,1)

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[5].getRange(1,1).activate(); //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lessen the number of loops, you can ​group it by determining the series of consecutive numbers in your Array. Which you can use to determine the index and number of rows to hide. The number of `.hideRows()` execution will be determined by the number of series in your array. Thus, lesser runtime.

**Example Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,13,14];

  const result = a.reduce((r, n) => {
    const lastSubArray = r[r.length - 1];
    if(!lastSubArray || lastSubArray[lastSubArray.length - 1] !== n - 1) {
      r.push([]);
    } 
    r[r.length - 1].push(n);
    return r;  
  }, []);
   
  //result output: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [11.0], [13.0, 14.0]]
  result.forEach(e => {
    var index = e[0];
    var numRows = e.length;
    Logger.log("Index: "+ index);
    Logger.log("numRows: "+numRows);
    // MyActiveSheet.hideRows(index,numRows);
  })  
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Ori Drori answer on how to group series of consecutive numbers in an Array.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47906920)
- [hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex,-numrows)